# How to run Method1 present in 100 classes in package using testng.xml?

Tags: automated-tests, testng, integration-testing

I have to Run the Method1 in Package whose structure looks like

```
Package - Regression
     |--class1
         |-method1
         |-method2
     |--class2
         |-method1
         |-method2
     |--class3 
     .
     .
     and so on goes to classN where N can be from 100 to 2000.
```

Now I need to write the testNG.xml is such a way that method1 present in all the classes execute at package level

or In future If i need to execute method1 and method2 at package level ?

Thanks in advance for solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily using a beanshell method selector.

Here's a sample

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="54859054_suite" verbose="2">
  <method-selectors>
    <method-selector>
      <script language="beanshell">
        <![CDATA[
        whatMethod = System.getProperty("methodToExecute", "testMethod1");
        method.getName().equals(whatMethod);
        ]]>
      </script>
    </method-selector>
  </method-selectors>
  <test name="54859054_test">
    <packages>
      <package name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn54859054"/>
    </packages>
  </test>
</suite>
```

The above beanshell by default will execute methods whose name is "testMethod1" (since its the default value we have provided for the JVM argument `methodToExecute`.

If you would like to change its value in run-time, you merely pass a new value via the JVM arugment. For e.g., `-DmethodToExecute=testMethod2`

Comment: This beanshell works for higher version of testing above testng12

Comment: Not sure what version are you referring to. Is that the testng Eclipse plugin version you are referring to? Oh btw the latest released version for TestNG is `7.0.0-beta3`